# Storing StringBuffer

Tags: java

I have a StringBuffer in my Class which deletes certain characters if the conditions are met in the IF statement and prints the statement. However, this could be repeated many times. If the second condition is met, the first statement will print out WITHOUT the characters being deleted.

Is there a way around this? Below is my code.

```
    if (status == 1 && item == item1[1]){
        item1[1] = "*"; 
        w = sb1.append(item1[1]+"["+item2[1]+"] ");
        sb1.delete(1,4);
    }else if (status == 1 && item == item1[2]){
        item1[2] = "*";
        x = sb1.append(item1[2]+"["+item2[2]+"] ");
        sb1.delete(1,4);
    }else if(status == 1 && item == item1[3]){
        item1[3] = "*";
        y = sb1.append(item1[3]+"["+item2[3]+"] ");
        sb1.delete(1,4);   
    }  
    return w.toString()+x.toString()+y.toString()+z.toString();
```

---

What i'm trying to achieve is the following:
I have a toString which is made up of:

item1[1]+"["item2[1]"] "+item1[2]+" ["+tem2[2]+"]"

I want to do this:

if item1 is marked as taken, it will be changed to "*" and remove the item2[1] and the  [ ] around it and then return it as:

```
     eg: item1[2] = x 
         item2[2] = 1


    * x[1]

( * used to be item1[1] )
```

but if the loops passes through again, my current class does this:
         *[] *[1]
i want it to be:
 * *
When the loop is complete

Comment: What is the problem on your code?

Comment: I find your question very hard to follow.  You don't state what your problem is, and you talk about printing, when there are no print statements in your code.

Comment: Question is not clear. Code is not clear. Please provide an example of input and expected outputs.

Comment: Seems to me you dont need w,x,y(,z) as they all hold only a reference to sb1. Your actually returning sb1 four times (if z holds a reference to sb1 as well)

Comment: As far as I can see, you are assigning sb1 to w, x, y.  Have you tried running your proram in a debugger to see what it is doing?

Answer (score 2):

A general problem: `item` looks like a `String`, `item[]` like a `String[]`. *Do not* use `==` with Strings, it will produce unexpected result occasionally. Use `equals()` instead:

```
if (status == 1 && item.equals(item1[1])) {
```

Use this pattern for the other conditional checks too.

(and add a test/handler for `item == null` which now would be necessary)

---

Another improvement: replace `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder` and don't concatenate Strings while passing them to append. Not to correct an error, but to give better performance:

```
 w = sb1.append(item1[1]).append("[").append(item2[1]).append("] ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks suspicious. Lets pull out the 3-times test whether 'status == 1' (is there a hidden boolean in the variable, which tries to come out?). And put some fresh air between the tokens, to make the job for the eye more easy to split them:

```
if (status == 1)
{
    if (item.equals (item1[1])) 
    {
        item1[1] = "*"; 
        w = sb1.append (item1[1] + "[" + item2[1] + "] ");
        sb1.delete (1, 4);
    } 
    else if (item.equals (item1[2]))
    {
        item1[2] = "*";
        x = sb1.append (item1[2] + "[" + item2[2] + "] ");
        sb1.delete (1, 4);
    }
    else if (item.equals (item1[3])) 
    {
        item1[3] = "*";
        y = sb1.append (item1[3] + "[" + item2[3] + "] ");
        sb1.delete (1, 4);   
    }
}  
return (w.append (x). append (y). append (z)).toString ();
//
```

Looks like 3times the same statement, just iterating through 1,2,3 and w,x,y. I used `append` in the last line too, and just put the 'toString ()' on the end result.

Let's make a loop from the 3 statements:

```
if (status == 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if (item.equals (item1[i])) 
        {
            item1[i] = "*"; 
            w = sb1.append (item1[i] + "[" + item2[i] + "] ");
            sb1.delete (1, 4);
        }
    }
}  
return (w.append (w). append (w). append (w)).toString ();
```

Depending on your code, sideeffects, threads and so on, this might result in something different, but I don't think so. Especially I don't know what w,x,y are by default, if not assigned in that code part. And the code looks, as if item is either equals item1[1] or item1[2] or item1[3] exclusively. But it might be equal to all 3, and then the loop will hit 3 times instead of 1 time.

However, item1/item2 is a code smell. It smells like 2-dim-array or not well thought of object orientation (item.color, item.name or something like that).